# Split DataTable into multiple DataTables based on column C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

I have uploaded a CSV file to a dataTable and now want to populate an existing database, however the values in the CSV file contain columns that need to be populated to multiple tables within the database. My theory is to split the dataTable down to multiple tables and then populate the database tables individually. First of all is this the best approach? Second how do I split the dataTables based on column name?

For Example I have uploaded a CSV file with the following headers:

Student_No, Surname, FirstName, Module_Code, Module_Name, Staff_No, Surname, Firstname.

I then want to split the datatables to:

**DataTable 1**

Student_No, Surname, FirstName

**DataTable 2**

Module_Code, Module_Name

**DataTable 3**

Staff_No, Surname, Firstname

All help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update!

I managed a workround of splitting the dataTables by column name by creating multiple dataTables by copying the DataTables and removing the columns that I did not need to populate my database.

```
private static DataTable SplitDataTableModule(DataTable d1)
    {

        DataTable dataTable1;
        dataTable1 = d1.Copy();
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(0); // remove student_no
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(1); // remove student surname
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(2); // remove student firstname
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(5); // remove staff_no
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(6); // remove staff surname
        dataTable1.Columns.RemoveAt(7); // remove staff firstname

        return d1;
    }
```